# Precise Multiplication

Tags: multiplication

first post!

I have a problem with a program that i'm writing for a numerical simulation and I have a problem with the multiplication. Basically, I am trying to calculate:

```
result1 = (a + b)*c
```

and this loops thousands of times. I need to expand this code to be

```
result2 = a*c + b*c
```

However, when I do that I start to get significant errors in my results. I used a high precision library, which did improve things, but the simulation ran horribly slow (the simulation took 50 times longer) and it really isn't a practical solution. From this I realised that it isn't really the precision of the variables a, b, & c that is hurting me, but something in the way the multiplication is done.

My question is: how can I multiply out these brackets in way so that result1 = result2?

Thanks.

SOLVED!!!!!!!!!

It was a problem with the addition. So i reordered the terms and applied Kahan addition by writing the following piece of code:

```
double Modelsimple::sum(double a, double b, double c, double d) {
    //reorder the variables in order from smallest to greatest
    double tempone = (a<b?a:b);
    double temptwo = (c<d?c:d);
    double tempthree = (a>b?a:b);
    double tempfour = (c>d?c:d);
    double one = (tempone<temptwo?tempone:temptwo);
    double four = (tempthree>tempfour?tempthree:tempfour);
    double tempfive = (tempone>temptwo?tempone:temptwo);
    double tempsix = (tempthree<tempfour?tempthree:tempfour);
    double two = (tempfive<tempsix?tempfive:tempsix);
    double three = (tempfive>tempsix?tempfive:tempsix);
    //kahan addition
    double total = one;
    double tempsum = one + two;
    double error = (tempsum - one) - two;
    total = tempsum;
    // first iteration complete
    double tempadd = three - error;
    tempsum = total + tempadd;
    error = (tempsum - total) - tempadd;
    total = tempsum;
    //second iteration complete
    tempadd = four - error;
    total += tempadd;
    return total;
}
```

This gives me results that are as close to the precise answer as makes no difference. However, in a fictitious simulation of a mine collapse, the code with the Kahan addition takes 2 minutes whereas the high precision library takes over a day to finish!!

Thanks to all the help here. This problem was really a pain in the a$$.

Comment: If the numbers are floating points, don't expect that `result1 = result2`. Read [this](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/FloatingPoint.aspx) or [this](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/05/why-do-computers-suck-at-math.html) for more details. If that doesn't answer the question, please post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) reproducing your results and add a tag to indicate the language.

Comment: Thanks, reading those now.

Comment: (Wikipedia on [Kahan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm)'s most famous contribution to improved numerical accuracy.) From your edit, I don't find it obvious _which_ `terms` you `reordered`. It would seem that the problem presentation missed the point (and still does).

Answer (score 0):

I am presuming your numbers are all floating point values.

You should not expect result1 to equal result2 due to limitations in the scale of the numbers and precision in the calculations. Which one to use will depend upon the numbers you are dealing with. More important than result1 and result2 being the same is that they are close enough to the real answer (eg that you would have calculated by hand) for your application.

Imagine that a and b are both very large, and c much less than 1. (a + b) might overflow so that result1 will be incorrect. result2 would not overflow because it scales everything down before adding.

There are also problems with loss of precision when combining numbers of widely differing size, as the smaller number has significant digits reduced when it is converted to use the same exponent as the larger number it is added to.

If you give some specific examples of a, b and c which are causing you issues it might be possible to suggest further improvements.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, they are floating point numbers and c is around 10^-5 and a and b are approximately 10^5 or significantly greater. There aren't other examples because c is essentially a strain, and b and c are constants that depend on the engineering properties of a material. It is this exact piece of arithmetic that is giving me the trouble. I only need to calculate b and c once and I can use the high precision library to do that, but the calculation with c happens often, possibly more than a million times.

Comment: Just wanted to clarify which variables you only calculate once (c is in both lists). Also when you mention that a and b may be significantly greater than 10^5, how large do you expect them to become? Is there often a large size difference between a and b?

Comment: C is passed to me and I am required to carry out the calculation above. I do calculate a and b, but only once. a and b can be as large as 10^10.

Comment: I have made a test program in c to do the calculation to look for loss of precision, but am having trouble finding any with the ranges for a,b and c you specify. I will post it as a separate answer, please let me know what you think.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using the following program as a test, using values for a and b between 10^5 and 10^10, and c around 10^-5, but so far cannot find any differences.

Thinking about the storage of 10^5 vs 10^10, I think it requires about 13 bits vs 33 bits, so you may lose about 20 bits of precision when you add a and b together in result1.

But multiplying them by the same value c essentially reduces the exponent but leaves the significand the same, so it should also lose about 20 bits of precision in result2.

A double significand usually stores 53 bits, so I suspect your results will still retain 33 bits, or about 10 decimal digits of precision.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  double a = 13584.9484893449;
  double b = 43719848748.3911;
  double c = 0.00001483394434;

  double result1 = (a+b)*c;
  double result2 = a*c + b*c;

  double diff = result1 - result2;

  printf("size of double is %d\n", sizeof(double));
  printf("a=%f\nb=%f\nc=%f\nr1=%f\nr2=%f\ndiff=%f\n",a,b,c,result1,result2,diff);
}
```

However I do find a difference if I change all the doubles to float and use c=0.00001083394434. Are you sure that you are using 64 (or 80) bit doubles when doing your calculations?

Comment: When i used to 64-bit version of the parent program and built the plugin as a 64-bit dll i didn't see any improvement in my problem. In fact, i have very little control over the format of 'c' and i am relying on the parent program to supply it to me. It is possible that i am still receiving a 32-bit double from the parent program even though i am using its 64-bit version.

Comment: Hi, i tried you program on my machine and i can't get any differences at all :(.

Comment: "It is possible I am still receiving a 32-bit double from the parent program". If that is so, then there will be a lot of zeros in the 64 bit representation of that number. Should be quite easy to check - and would explain a lot of what you are seeing.

Answer (score 0):

Usually "loss of precision" in these kinds of calculations can be traced to "poorly formulated problem". For example, when you have to add a series of numbers of very different sizes, you will get a different answer depending on the order in which you sum them. The problem is even more acute when you subtract numbers.

The best approach in your case above is to look not simply at this one line, but at the way that `result1` is used in your subsequent calculations. In principle, an engineering calculation should not require precision in the final result beyond about three significant figures; but in many instances (for example, finite element methods) you end up subtracting two numbers that are very similar in magnitude - in which case you may lose many significant figures and get a meaningless answer. Given that you are talking about "materials properties" and "strain", I am suspecting that is actually at the heart of your problem.

One approach is to look at places where you compute a difference, and see if you can reformulate your problem (for example, if you can differentiate your function, you can replace `Y(x+dx)-Y(x)` with `dx * Y(x)'`.

There are many excellent references on the subject of numerical stability. It is a complicated subject. Just "throwing more significant figures at the problem" is almost never the best solution.

Comment: Thanks. I would like to take into account your suggestions, unfortunately i don't have the level of control over the parent program to be able to do that.

Comment: Unfortunately "numerical instability" is something that can only be solved by addressing the _whole_ problem. Is there some other way you can "cheat" (sometimes, if the system is strictly linear, or deviations are sufficiently small you can treat it as such, you could multiply the "apparent deflection" by 100x or so and improve stability.) In other cases, changing the frame of reference or re-scaling dimensions can help (e.g. centering your data about zero). Good luck.

Comment: Yes, i have been using a high precision library to solve the problem and i think that the cheats are the way to go because otherwise the problem runs far too slowly. Do you know of any other cheats. I was thinking of exp(log(a)+log(b)) for the multiplication.

Comment: I think the problem lies in the addition, not the multiplication. When `a` and `b` have very different magnitude, you will lose precision of the smaller number during summation - whether before or after multiplication. Unless you can change the way you use these numbers, higher precision will only "delay the inevitable"

Comment: Ok, i will experiment with controlling the error during addition and seeing what improvements i can make, thanks.